# ACS712 over current switch

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

[image]

The circuit is from [here.](https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/current-sensor-amplifier-current-switch)

[image]

The output logic is LOW at over current.  Is it correct?

If U2B pin 5 is set to 2V, U2B pin 6 is 2.5V (zero current), OUT is low.

Higher current –> Lower U2B pin 6 voltage.

If U2B pin 6 goes to lower than 2V, OUT is high.

Comment: No, it's not correct (based on the info you provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACS714 measure **DC** and **AC** current.

See characteristic Vout vs Current.

With DC current, if "logic" is not good, swap IP pins... But only in "some cases" ... See pictures !

Simulated with microcap v12 , http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Offsets may change results. Text "Sweeping ..." Step = 1. Sorry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.

Vcc to IP+,  IP- to Load  
HIGH at OverCurrent,   

Vcc to IP-,  IP+ to Load  
LOW at OverCurrent,     

am I correct ?

Comment: I added some pictures with  a change of op amps. A bit complicated with some op amps ...

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot.